# Wordpress redirect to custom .php file with vars

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have a function that redirects custom requests to a custom .php file in my theme and it works great.

The problem happens when I need to redirect with URL vars, it throws a 404 not found.

The function is as follow:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function(){

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/abc.php') {

        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->is_404 = false;
        status_header(200);
        include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../path/xyz.php');
        exit();

     }
});
```

The file `abc.php` gets dynamic vars, for example `abc.php?orderID=12345`.

So what I basically need, is to pass the dynamic `?orderID=12345` from `abc.php` to `xyz.php` so it becomes `xyz.php?orderID=12345`.

How can I achieve it by modifying the function above without creating new pages or assigning templates?

Comment: Because your are including there is no redirect. So you can use `$_GET['orderID']`.

Comment: I’ve tried already with $_GET[‘orderID’] before writing here. It still doesn’t work. abc.php is not an actual page as well as the xyz.php they are just scripts to handle some stuff.

Comment: You should do `strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/abc.php', -8) !== false`, because sometimes the scheme (https://)  or domain is included. Then your comparision is wrong.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Nope, Still didn't do the trick. I still get error in the console: example.com/abc.php?orderID=12345 404 (not found). And the script in xyz.php isn't executed. It's like it never visits the xyz.php at all.

Comment: Maybe it conflicts with the rewrite rules of Wordpress. In that case I would do a redirect inside the webservers vhost like `Redirect 301 /abc.php /xyz.php`.

Comment: @MarkusZeller you were close. Found a solution. It should be `if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/abc.php?orderID=') === 0) {}`